# I try to push my site to Heroku, but I got these errors.

Tags: python, django, heroku

I tried to push this to Heroku site, I can run it locally without any problems so far. But when I pushed it to Heroku, I got these errors. I don't understand these errors, I tried to search the internet for these errors code. unfortunately, I couldn't find anything about it. If you know something about this please help me find a solution for this. Thanks.

This is a error that I got when I tried to link to my page in Heroku domain.

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: https://pawkanstyleblog.herokuapp.com/

Django Version: 1.10.5
Python Version: 3.5.2
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'web.firstpage',
 'django_ajax']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']


Template error:
In template /app/web/firstpage/templates/firstpage/index.html, error at line 47
   relation "firstpage_project" does not exist
LINE 1: ..."."create_date", "firstpage_project"."image" FROM "firstpage...
                                                             ^
   37 :             </h1>
   38 :             <h1 class="text-center hidden-md-up" >PROJECTS</h1>
   39 :              <i class="fa fa-grav fa-5x pl-4 hidden-sm-down" aria-hidden="true" ></i>
   40 :         </div>
   41 :         <div class="row">
   42 :             <div class="col-md-12 pt-4">
   43 :                 <div class="card-columns">
   44 : 
   45 :                     {% load tz %}
   46 : 
   47 :                     {% for project in projects %} 
   48 : 
   49 :                   <a href="{% url 'firstpage:detail' project.pk %}">
   50 :                   <div class="card ">
   51 :                     <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="{{ project.image.url}}" alt="Card image cap">
   52 :                     <div class="card-block" id="card-front">
   53 :                       <h4 class="card-title">{{project.title | title}}</h4>
   54 :                       <p class="card-text">{{project.description | truncatewords:50 }}</p>
   55 :                       <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">{{project.create_date | timezone:"Asia/Bangkok"}} </small></p>
   56 :                     </div>
   57 :                   </div>


Traceback:

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  64.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

The above exception (relation "firstpage_project" does not exist
LINE 1: ..."."create_date", "firstpage_project"."image" FROM "firstpage...
                                                             ^
) was the direct cause of the following exception:

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  39.             response = get_response(request)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/app/web/firstpage/views.py" in index
  15.     return render(request,'firstpage/index.html',{'projects': projects,'contacts':contacts})

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py" in render
  30.     content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/loader.py" in render_to_string
  68.     return template.render(context, request)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py" in render
  66.             return self.template.render(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  208.                     return self._render(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  199.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  994.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  961.             return self.render(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  174.         return compiled_parent._render(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  199.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  994.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  961.             return self.render(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  70.                 result = block.nodelist.render(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  994.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  961.             return self.render(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
  166.             len_values = len(values)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in __len__
  238.         self._fetch_all()

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in _fetch_all
  1087.             self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in __iter__
  54.         results = compiler.execute_sql()

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
  835.             cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  79.             return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  64.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/utils.py" in __exit__
  94.                 six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/six.py" in reraise
  685.             raise value.with_traceback(tb)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  64.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

Exception Type: ProgrammingError at /
Exception Value: relation "firstpage_project" does not exist
LINE 1: ..."."create_date", "firstpage_project"."image" FROM "firstpage...
                                                             ^
```

This is my setting.py.

```
"""
Django settings for web project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.10.5.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/
"""

import os
import dj_database_url

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))





# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '*******************************'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'web.firstpage',
    'django_ajax',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'web.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'web.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': '*************',
        'USER': '**********',
        'PASSWORD': '*********',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'




# Update database configuration with $DATABASE_URL.
db_from_env = dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=500)
DATABASES['default'].update(db_from_env)

# Extra places for collectstatic to find static files.
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static'),
)

SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.django.GzipManifestStaticFilesStorage'
```

Comment: You don't have a project named `firstpage_project` instead you have `firstpage` so check your `index.html` first line.

Comment: Does this works locally? If it does, try running migrations when you pushed to heroku

Comment: What database are you using locally?